# Why do I spawn randomly when copying my singleplayer world into a multiplayer server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

When I place my Singleplayer map in my server I spawn randomly! I've checked, the world isn't using the same seed.

I copy the world, paste it into the server, delete the folder called 'world' and rename the new map, 'world'.

Comment: Check server's configuration in `server.properties`. For example, there is a value for world seed there, it should probably match yours. Sorry can't check for myself right now.

Comment: what do u mean how dose that make a difference?

Comment: sorry what i meant was if the wold will have the seed yes, but the structures will not be there...

Comment: The seed determines the world that will be generated further, when you travel - you want this to be the same world as your singleplayer one. If the problem is that the existing terrain is not moved, then there is probably a difference in formats. I'll try to test later today. What version are you playing?

Comment: 1.7.4 is the version i am playing now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `server.properties` file, ensure that `level-seed=` is the same as the singleplayer world seed.

Once this has been changed, recopy the `world` folder, then start your server back up. You should spawn in the same place. Also ensure that the singleplayer level world, and your server are on the same version.

Comment: what server back up?

Comment: OMG THANK YOU SOOOOOOOOOO MUCH IT WORKED!!!!!!!!!!!!! XD XD thank you,! thank you,! thank you,!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @diana You can select my answer as accepted by clicking on the "checkmark" to the left of my answer.

Comment: Ok I did that. Thank you so much though.... it really helped!!!!!